# How do I properly configure Cassandra in EC2 to connect to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, nosql

I have an **AWS EC2** instance with **Centos 8**.

Inside this instance, I have successfully installed the **Cassandra** (*3.11.10*) database.

Inside this database, I have successfully created keyspace via this **CQL** query:

```
create keyspace if not exists dev_keyspace with replication={'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 2};
```

Then I edited **configurion file** (`/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml`):

```
cluster_name: "DevCluster"
seeds: <ec2_private_ip_address>
listen_address: <ec2_private_ip_address>
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: <ec2_private_ip_address>
endpoint_snitch: Ec2Snitch
```

After that, restarted database:

```
Datacenter: eu-central
======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address                   Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  <ec2_private_ip_address>  75.71 KiB  256          100.0%            XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX  1a
```

When I try to connect to the Cassandra database with such credentials it raise an error:

```
host: <ec2_public_ip_address>
port: 9042
keyspace: dev_keyspace
username: cassandra (default)
password: cassandra (default)
```

**ERROR**:

> All host(s) tried for query failed (tried:
> /<ec2_private_ip_address>:9042
> (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException:
> [/<ec2_private_ip_address>:9042] Cannot connect))

What did I forget to configure? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Are you trying to connect from a different instance? did you configure the security group to allow the connections?

Comment: I tried to connect to the database via software applications like `DBeaver` or `DataGrip` from my local computer. In fact, I have the standard settings for the `Security Group`. `Type`: `SSH`, `Protocol`: `TCP`; `Port range`: `22`; `Source`: `0.0.0.0/0`. In the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html), there are a couple of examples of what settings should be for relational databases. What settings do I need to make in the Security Group section for the Cassandra database?

Comment: Well, I changed the `Inbound Rules` of the `Security Group`. I opened the `port range` (`0 - 65535`). After that, I was able to connect to the Cassandra database. It's probably not safe to open all ports.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to access your cluster remotely because you've configured Cassandra to only listen for clients on the private IP with this setting:

```
broadcast_rpc_address: <ec2_private_ip_address>
```

For the node to accept requests from external clients, you need to set the following in `cassandra.yaml`:

```
listen_address: private_ip
rpc_address: public_ip
```

Note that you don't need to set the broadcast RPC address. You will need to restart Cassandra for the changes to take effect.

You will also need to define a security group with **inbound rules** on the AWS Management Console to allow ingress to your EC2 instances on port `9042`. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to apply your recommendations, but I ran into a problem. Could you please direct me in the right direction? I set `listen_address: 'ec2_private_ip_address'` and `rpc_address: 'ec2_public_ip_address'`. I also removed  `broadcast_rpc_address` from the `cassandra.yaml` file as you recommended. Cleared the system cache (`nodetool flush system`) and restarted the Cassandra service: (`sudo systemctl restart cassandra`). After that, I tried to connect to the Cassandra database. It raises the same error as I described earlier.

Comment: I can connect only if I have this settings `rpc_address: 0.0.0.0` and `broadcast_rpc_address: 'ec2_private_ip_address`.

Comment: The `9042` port is opened. I set this up in the `inbound rules` of the `security groups`.